# MVVM with dynamic the Michrochart-NugetPackage doesn't work

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, charts

I want to add a dynamic micro chart to my application but it doesn't work. After a call from a method a value gets added and it makes a completely new micro chart for my chart to have the new values, but the change isn't visible in the app. So the old Values stayed and there is no new one. Thanks for helping me.

```
WeightList = new List<float>();
        WeightList.Add(0);
        WeightList.Add((float)74.3);
        entries = new ChartEntry[30];
        SyncArray();

private void SyncArray()
    {
        if (WeightList.Count != entries.Length)
        {
            entries = new ChartEntry[WeightList.Count];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= WeightList.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (i == WeightList.Count - 1 || i == 0)
            {
                entries[i] = new ChartEntry(WeightList[i]) { Label = "" + i, ValueLabel = "" + WeightList[i] };
            }
            else
            {
                entries[i] = new ChartEntry(WeightList[i]) { Label = "" + i };
            }
        }
        chart = new LineChart() { Entries = entries, BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent };
        Chart = chart;
    }

public LineChart Chart
    {
        get => chart;
        set => SetProperty(ref chart, value);
    }

public float Weight
    {
        get => weight;
        set
        {
            weight = value;
            WeightList.Add(weight);
            SyncArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: there is not enough code here to determine what exactly is wrong.  But to start with, you don't need to assign both the private `chart` field AND the public `Chart` property.  Just assign the public property, which will set the private field for you.

Comment: @Jason Hi, first of all thanks for helping me. What would you need to determine the mistake?

Comment: see [mcve].  You have not posted the XAML that demonstrates how the chart is being bound, and the code snippet at the top of your example is completely lacking any context.  Where is this code called?  Why are you making a "completely new chart" if all you want to do is add values to the existing chart?

Comment: This is my Xaml <microcharts:ChartView x:Name="chartViewLine" HeightRequest="300" Margin="0,10,0,0" Chart="{Binding Chart, Mode=TwoWay}"/>. The reason why I add a new chart is because micro chart has no method to add a single value. You have to add a completely new chart. The Getter-Call comes through a View Change, The getter got set through another class. @Jason

Comment: The reason why I add a new chart is because michrocharts has no mehtode to add a single value. You have to add a completely new chart. The Getter-Call comes through a

Comment: did you fix the problem I noted in my first comment?

Comment: @Jason Hi I tried it and it worked thank you very much that you helped me. See you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credits: @Jason
What to change:

```
private void SyncArray()
{
    if (WeightList.Count != entries.Length)
    {
        entries = new ChartEntry[WeightList.Count];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= WeightList.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (i == WeightList.Count - 1 || i == 0)
        {
            entries[i] = new ChartEntry(WeightList[i]) { Label = "" + i, ValueLabel = "" + WeightList[i] };
        }
        else
        {
            entries[i] = new ChartEntry(WeightList[i]) { Label = "" + i };
        }
    }
    Chart = new LineChart() { Entries = entries, BackgroundColor = SKColors.Transparent };
}
```